# Script not working on iPhone6 Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, ios, safari

I've got a Wordpress form (Fluent Forms Pro) with a dropdown list, and some jQuery loading in the footer that automatically chooses an item from the list depending on the querystring 'category' value.

It works everywhere apart from on iPhone Safari and Chrome on an iPhone 6. Can anyone see why it's not working on those devices?

```js
if (typeof urlParams !== 'undefined') {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
} else {
  urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
}

myParam = urlParams.get('category');

(function($) {
  $.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
  
  $('.form-category-select option:icontains(' + myParam + ')').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == myParam.toLowerCase()) {
      $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery selects the correct option name (not value) compared to the 'category' querystring (case insensitive):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="form_element" id="ff_6_form_element" class="ff-el-form-control form-category-select" type="select" data-name="form_element" data-calc_value="0" tabindex="1">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="87">Category 1</option>
  <option value="124">Category 2</option>
  <option value="79" selected="selected">Category 3</option>
  <option value="190">Category 4</option>
  <option value="138">Category 5</option>
  <option value="108">Category 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Also - do you ***really*** need to still support an iPhone 6?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using jQuery 3.6.0 and yes, I do need to support the iPhone 6 at the moment.

Comment: I'd suggest trying jQuery 1.12, as a lot of legacy browser support was removed from 2.x and 3.x. It's going to be difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing any errors, though. Does the site work when you use Chrome in mobile browser mode on desktop? To test this, open Chrome devtools then press CTRL + SHIFT + M

Comment: Thanks for that. It does work in Chrome devtools in mobile mode. That gives me enough to tell them that iPhone 6 can't be supported any more - thanks for your help.